# Overriding JS functions in LWC Component from the wrapper component without touching the internals

Tags: lightning-web-components

We have a table component built in LWC. There is a button, on click of which the rows will be sorted based on some logic. All this markup is a part of the table component. This sorting function is also decorated with @api, so that we can execute this function from the parent (wrapper) component.

Now we are looking for a way so that we can override the sort logic that is already built inside the table component, and provide our own custom logic from the parent (wrapper) component. **We really don't want to touch the table component.**

This is something like the owner of the component has exposed few APIs to the outer world, and we have to implement these methods. Is this possible in LWC?

Comment: How about "search it in the wrapper component, then pass to the child?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke sort function of table which is a click function, you will get `event` property by default which is of type `object`. You can leverage this to pass in your own function because the type of function will be `function`.

`handleSort` method in **table** component js:

```
data = [ { name: 3 }, { name: 1 }, { name: 2 }, { name: 4 } ];
@api
handleSort(eventOrFunction) {
    if (typeof eventOrFunction === 'function') {
        console.log('handleSort function passed from wrapper');
        this.data.sort(eventOrFunction);
    } else {
        // default sort
        console.log('handleSort invoked in CHILD');
        this.data.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
            return -1;
        });
    }
    console.log('sorted data => ', JSON.stringify(this.data));
}
```

Now, you can pass your own function for sort from **wrapper** component:

```
sortChildData() {
    let parentSortFunc = (a, b) => {
        if (a.name > b.name) return -1;
        return 1;
    };
    this.template.querySelector('c-child').handleSort(parentSortFunc);
}
```

[Here is the playground example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/BeE-Eneut/1/edit)